# Flag for migration declined

Tags: discussion, flags, migration, declined-flags

This is the question: [Is this a good way to code a struct for logged locks via the 'using' construct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776028/is-this-a-good-way-to-code-a-struct-for-logged-locks-via-the-using-construct)

I have flagged it with: "belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com"

My flag was declined with:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Was it correct declined?

I think if someone one to make working code better or discuss it 
[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the right place for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators cannot migrate any question over 60 days old.

They will have to reject any requests to migrate the old and creaky.

Comment: It seems like "no evidence to support it" was not an ideal message to explain the reason for declining the flag, then. Maybe a custom message would've been better?

Comment: One might ask why is it even possible to ask for migration if it is impossible to grant it?

Comment: That was a free text option. You can ask for many things, but many things aren't all possible. @dar

Comment: @daramarak It is not possible to ask for migration automatically when the question is too old--i.e., that doesn't appear as an option when voting/flagging for closure. However, after a question is closed, the only way to flag to request migration is with a custom flag. It's not wrong to use a custom flag to ask for migration, but as random says, the system cannot (or at least does not) heuristically examine the content of a custom flag reason to prevent migration requests on unmigratable questions.

Comment: I see, I didn't see that from the answer. Not an err at SOs side then. Strange about the 60 days limit, but I guess there are many questions covering that also.

Comment: @random - you are right, That was a free text option.

Comment: @random - the explanation was not 100% clear =) I mean explanation why it was declined

Comment: @random - after my second attempt to flag it - I have it " declined - Questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated. " Thanks! )

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you have a point. After all his question boils down to "please review my code"

After all the SO site should for the most part have objective answers, but such a review would demand a much more subjective view, after all good and bad code depends much on style and experience.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your flag should have been considered unsupported by evidence, but **I think even this decline reason was reasonable**.

(As [random says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169573/185080), it had to be declined *even if there was good evidence to support it*, so I'm talking about something a little bit different from the question of *whether or not it should have been declined*. Furthermore, if that decline reason was *borderline applicable* but not really the reason the flag was declined, a custom reason would still have been better.)

- On the one hand, as daramarak implies, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is an appropriate place to ask "Should it work this way?" and "How can this do X better?" questions about *working code*. And the code in the question is presented as working (just *possibly* non-ideal, or that was the author's concern).
- On the other hand, the post was probably completely on-topic and constructive on Stack Overflow. While answers would have been subjective (as [daramarak says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169572/185080)), they could easily be supported by evidence and narrowly scoped.

  Plenty of perfectly good questions on Stack Overflow have multiple perfectly good answers that disagree with each other. It's certainly true that subjective questions tend to be less appropriate on Stack Overflow than on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) still applies, and this question seems to fall on the "good" side (by the six criteria listed there).

  If a question is clear, on-topic, and constructive for Stack Overflow, then unless the OP requests migration, it should not be migrated to another site *even if it would probably have been better to ask it there*. Being a clearer fit somewhere else [does not make it off-topic for SO](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).